# Why isn't range getting exhausted in Python-3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, range

If I do the following:

```
a = range(9)

for i in a:
    print(i)

# Must be exhausted by now
for i in a:
    print(i)

# It starts over!
```

Python's generators, after raising `StopIteration`, normally stops looping.  How then is range producing this pattern - it restarts after every iteration.

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range)?

Comment: In short: the  `for i in a` construct is generating a separate iterable each time...

Comment: What made you think `range()` is an iterator? (Generators are a specialised form of iterators, it is iterators that raise `StopIteration`).

Comment: Please excuse my not knowing the difference between the two. Part of the reason why I thought that way was because `range` being instantiated, like `a=range(9)`, is very much similar to how a generator is instantiated in order to get an iterator. My mistake.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I did, but couldn't find what I was looking for. Perhaps I should *learn how to read the docs* first!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As has been stated by others, `range` is not a generator, but sequence type (like list) that makes it an `iterable` which is NOT the same as an `iterator`.

The differences between `iterable`, `iterator` and `generator` are subtle (at least for someone new to python).

- An `iterator` provides a `__next__` method and can be exhausted, thus raising `StopIteration`.
- An `iterable` is a object that provides an `iterator` over its content. Whenever its `__iter__` method is called it returns a NEW iterator object, thus you can (indirectly) iterate over it multiple times.
- A `generator` is a function that returns an `iterator`, which of cause can be exhausted.
- Also good to know is, that the `for` loop automaticly queries the `iterator` of any `iterable`. Which is why you can write `for x in iterable: pass` instead of `for x in iterable.__iter__(): pass` or `for x in iter(iterable): pass`.

All of that IS in the documentation, but IMHO somewhat difficult to find. The best starting point is probably the [Glossary](https://docs.python.org/3.4/glossary.html#term-iterable).

Comment: Upvoting for explicitly mentioning the difference between iterator and iterable.

Answer (score 4):

[`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range) is a kind of immutable sequence type. Iterating it does not exhaust it.

```
>>> a = iter(range(9))  # explicitly convert to iterator
>>>
>>> for i in a:
...     print(i)
...
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
>>> for i in a:
...     print(i)
...
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

`range` is not a generator, it's a [sequence type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range), like [strings or lists](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq).

So

```
for i in range(4):
```

is no different than

```
for i in "abcd":
```